# WordPress: on submitting post check if post is updated

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress with the `publish_{post_type}` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) you can hook into the loop if a post with custom type is published. But `publish_{post_type}` is also triggers if a a post is updated.

I am basically looking for a way to check the old and new status, within the `publish_post_type` hook. Does anyone have a nifty idea as to how to accomplish that?

I am doing this:

```
function doStuff( $post_ID ) {
    // do stuff
    return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'publish_ttplaned', 'doStuff' );
```

So basically I need to check the old and new status of the post within the fuction doStuff().

Comment: `publish_post_type` isn't a WordPress hook...Or are you just referring to `post_type` as a placeholder for your actual post type? If so, I don't understand the question

Comment: @mevius Sorry I was reffering to {status}_{post_type} transition: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is looking for the aswer. I ended up using Williams solution.

```
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'doStuff', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'doStuff', 10, 1 );
function doStuff( $post ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post ) == "my_custom_post_type" ){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This works since a new post starts out as a draft even if you publish it right away.

Answer (score 0):

As @rnevius says, there's no hook in WordPress core called `publish_post_type`.

There is also [`publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) - which I've just tested it to make sure it only runs when the post is first published, not when it's subsequently edited.

So you can do something like:

```
function my_function($post_ID, $post) {
  if ("foo" == $post->post_type) {
    // do something
  }
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'my_function', 10, 2 );
```

There is also the `wp_transition_post_status()`, which calls several actions:

`transition_post_status` with `$new_status`, `$old_status`, `$post`

or, if you want to do it the other way around:

`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}` and passes a `WP_Post` object as the only parameter.

Comment: You can use any pattern that follows `{status}_{post_type}`. So if you have a custom post type called `kittens` you could use the `'publish_kittens'` hook.

Comment: I have edited my question, hopefully making it more clear what I am asking :)

sry for any confusion :)

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with the `{old_status}_to_{new_status}` hook, or `transition_post_status`?

Comment: nope but I am looking into WP_TRANSITION_POST_STATUS I think I might be able to hack something with that... I'll get back to you if I succeed :)

Comment: @WilliamTurrell You were right. testing for draft_to_publish and pending_to_publish did the trick, since a new post passes the draft stage before getting published. Thanks for the hint :)